# How to apply an xls transformation to a Word document

Tags: javascript, xslt, ms-word

I'm trying to make a small MS Word java application and trying to apply an XSLT to an XML output from Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync function.
Here is the part of the code:

```js
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Ooxml, function (result)
                {
                    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded)
                    {
                        var parser = new DOMParser();
                        var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(result.value, "text/xml");

                        var xsltTree = new XMLHttpRequest();
   
                        
                        xsltTree.open('GET', "a.xslt", false);

                        var xslProc = xsltTree.createProcesor();
                        xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
                        xslProc.transform();

                        var resTree = xslProc.output; 

                   }
                    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(val, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Text }, function (result) 
                    {
                        // Access the results, if necessary.
                    }
                  );
```

new XSLTProcessor() also fails. :(

I can't find how to create an XSLT processor (it fails with error) or any other way to apply an XSLT to it.

I hope someone can point me to the right solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Microsoft only supports XSLT by using MSXML, so with Javascript you need to make sure you create an MSXML DOM document and processor e.g. `var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0'); doc.loadXML(result.value);`. If you don't want to pass in any parameters then the easiest is using the `transformNode` method exposed on `doc`: `var sheet = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0'); sheet.async = false; sheet.load('a.xslt'); var result = doc.transformNode(sheet);`. This is what I would try, but I have never used Javascript with Word.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Unfortunately it doesn't work. I can't create new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0"), so for an XML documents I use new DOMParser(). But I can't find a corresponding class for an XSLT, that will work. :(

Comment: Might not be relevant, but `.createProcesor()` is spelled wrong, it should be `.createProcessor()`.

Comment: It seems to be quite relevant, since the type is also in the code example.